# Issue with returning a char

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, char, return-type

I don't understand why I am getting an error stating that the method getClassification must return a result of type char.

```
private char A, B, C, D;

public char getClassification() {
    if(parts[0] >= 0 && parts[0] <= 127)
        return (A);
    else if(parts[0] >= 128 && parts[0] <= 191)
        return (B);
    else if(parts[0] >= 192 && parts[0] <= 223)
        return (C);
    else if(parts[0] >= 224 && parts[0] <= 255)
        return (D);
}
```

Comment: It's because all of your return statements are conditional. If all conditions are false, method will reach the end without returning anything.

Comment: You need either, as stated in answers and comments, a 'default' `return` statement **or** if that `case` should never occur in your programm, you should `throw` an `[Runtime]Exception`. See [Fail Fast principle](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:fail_fast).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getClassification` doesn't return a value when all the if condition is false.

```
private char A, B, C, D;

public char getClassification() {
    if(parts[0] >= 0 && parts[0] <= 127)
        return (A);
    else if(parts[0] >= 128 && parts[0] <= 191)
        return (B);
    else if(parts[0] >= 192 && parts[0] <= 223)
        return (C);
    else if(parts[0] >= 224 && parts[0] <= 255)
        return (D);
    else
       return //Something Else(char Value)
}
```

This should Work.

Comment: Doesn't matter, even if you put `true` in each `if` statement (as `if(true)`), the compiler will complain. So the explanation is not 100% correct.

Comment: Instead of the default `return` statement, a `throw  new SomeException()` should be considered, if that's an _illegal state_ in that part of the code. // BTW, the `else` helps for verbosity but could also be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Need an else statement or default return statement

Comment: This needs more explanation to be a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have put every `return` statement inside an `if` statement.

The compiler is not smart enough to figure out the surety of what you are returning from the function when you put all the `return` statement inside `if` condition (*even if the function is definitely going to return the mentioned type*).

Try compiling it, the compiler will **complain** the same thing:

```
public char getClassification() {
    if(true) return 'a';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning character a,b,c,d depending on if condition but in some conditions if all conditions are false (e.g parts[0] >255 or parts[0] <0)  then function returns nothing.To avoid the error write else condition at the end.

```js
private char A, B, C, D;

public char getClassification() {
    if(parts[0] >= 0 && parts[0] <= 127)
        return (A);
    else if(parts[0] >= 128 && parts[0] <= 191)
        return (B);
    else if(parts[0] >= 192 && parts[0] <= 223)
        return (C);
    else if(parts[0] >= 224 && parts[0] <= 255)
        return (D);
    else
        return 'E';
}
```

> private char A, B, C, D;
>
> public char getClassification() {
>
> if(parts[0] >= 0 && parts[0] <= 127)
>   return (A);

```
else if(parts[0] >= 128 && parts[0] <= 191)
    return (B);
else if(parts[0] >= 192 && parts[0] <= 223)
    return (C);
else if(parts[0] >= 224 && parts[0] <= 255)
    return (D);
```

}